# Does Azure Event Grid support cloud event schema version 0.2?

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid, cloudevents

I know that the AEG (azure event grid) works with cloud schema 0.1 as shown here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/cloudevents-schema#cloudevent-schema.

But the cloud event schema latest version is 0.2 at https://github.com/cloudevents/spec/blob/master/spec.md.

1. I tried to follow the schema for 0.2 to see if it works. It did not. May be that is just me. Has any one tried with 0.2?
2. Is it supported or not?

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/cloudevents-schema) doesn't say anything about 0.2, but I'm confident it will be coming shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Cloud Event Schema V0.2 is not supported in Azure Event Grid (support for it is expected to be added in the next few months).